# How to show that $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\over (xy)^{-1}-xy}\cdot{(-\ln(xy))^k}={1\over 2^{k+2}}\Gamma(k+2)\zeta(k+2)?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Proposed: Double integral

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\mathrm dx\mathrm dy\over (xy)^{-1}-xy}\cdot{(-\ln(xy))^k}={1\over 2^{k+2}}\Gamma(k+2)\zeta(k+2)\tag1$$
>   $k\ge 0$

**My try:**

I have no idea where to start

**How can one prove $(1)?$**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I$ be the integral given by $I=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{(-1)^k\log^k(xy)}{\frac{1}{xy}-xy}\,dx\,dy$.  Enforcing the substitution $xy\to x$ in the inner integral and interchanging the order of integration reveals

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{(-1)^k\log^k(xy)}{\frac{1}{xy}-xy}\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=\int_0^1\frac1y\int_0^y \frac{(-1)^kx\log^k(x)}{1-x^2}\,dx\,dy\\\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac{(-1)^kx\log^{k+1}(x)}{1-x^2}\,dx\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Next, enforcing the substitution $x\to e^{-x}$ in the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$, writing $\frac{1}{1-e^{-2x}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-2nx}$, interchanging the order of summation and integration, and enforcing the substitution $2nx\to x$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1\frac{ e^{-2x}x^{k+1}}{1-e^{-2x}}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 x^{k+1}e^{-2nx}\,dx\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n)^{k+2}}\int_0^\infty x^{k+1}e^{-x}\,dx\\\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{k+2}}\Gamma(k+1)\zeta(k+2)
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!